# Why did the government made Project TOR public?

Tags: tor

It was originally created by the government for their own use; why did they make it public? 
Making TOR public also meant the dark web now became accessible to the public. Was the deep web accessible before Project TOR came into existence?
And making it public also meant that it could also be used against them;  criminals also use it for secure communication.

Comment: I think you might be overstating things a little to say that "the government developed it for their own use". Once you rethink that one assertion, your question kind of falls down.

Comment: Believe me if you ask US Navy now why they made it public, they regret it. NSA is having a hard time to shutdown illegal darkweb sites. When one is shut down, one is hosted again with new version. They wanted to offer it for journalists and whistleblowers but soon it started attracting criminals too.

Answer (score 10):

There are certainly a lot of reasons which we could speculate about, but one is fact and inherent in the way Tor works to provide anonymity to its users:

If the "government" (or rather, the united states naval research lab) was the only one to use Tor, then obviously they wouldn't gain any anonymity. Someone who noticed traffic from a Tor exit node would immediately know that someone from that research lab was behind the requests.

So by making it public and encouraging a wide variety of people from all walks of life to set up exit nodes and use Tor as a client, it becomes possible to hide in the mass of people who use Tor. So if you use Tor, it might be because you want to buy illegal drugs, but it might also be because you're a whistleblower or a human rights activist, or simply worried about your privacy on the internet.

Since the US law enforcement, government and intelligence agencies and armed forces sometimes require anonymity for their communication, too (that's why Tor was birthed, after all), diversification of the Tor user base would be something they'd be interested in, and that can't be achieved by keeping Tor use limited to US government agencies.

Answer (score 0):

The stated purpose of tor was to give citizens in censored nations access to a tool to bypass censorship. They have to have access to the tool for that to happen, and by far the easiest way to do that is to make it available to the general public.

Answer (score -3):

In my reasoning (or rather guess) the government hoped (and which is later actually happened) that there will be on the Internet certain networks of the genre Tor that will be trusted for safety and fairly widely used by the general public. A sufficiently powerful secret agency can however, among other actions, tap at the entry point of the ISP of a user (and/or at the entry point of the nodes of a Tor-like network) and detect from the IP address of the emails that the user is sending messages to nodes of a Tor-like network so that the user will then become suspicious in the view of the agency. I suppose this alone is worthy of the efforts of the government to publish their own work on Tor. (Note that my point concerns the senders, not the receivers, of messages through Tor.)

Comment: While we now know that intelligence agencies take an active interest in TOR users, what you describe sounds a lot like a movie plot. It's much more likely that actively looking for TOR traffic is a reaction to the creation of the global TOR network, not the ultimate goal of creating it in the first place. The Snowden documents support this view; they do not sound as if the NSA was very happy about TOR. Also, if the network was really used widely by the general public, you couldn't use it to identify suspicious people.

Comment: Note that like all governments, the US Government is not a single entity. Tor was originally developed by the US Navy, while it's the NSA that wanted to be able to snoop on Tor users.

Comment: @Pascal: I wrote I was guessing. You may be right. On the other hand, there are claims sometimes seen on the Internet in the direction that using TOR is "entirely" safe and I was arguing that this could not be the case. To your last sentence: I suppose that the authority can first use some other criteria to sieve out persons to be more closely examined and, if part of these persons are found to be using TOR, then it could be more profitable for the authority to concentrate their investigation efforts on that subset of persons (noting that their resouces, though huge, are yet finite).